# Histogram bars exceed chart area in R

Tags: r, histogram

I am creating a histogram with the following line:

```
hist(mydata$freq2,col="lightgreen")
```

This produces the image below:

[image]

I would like the bars to stay within the chart area. Why doesn't R increase the values of the X and Y axis, and how can I increase these values manually?

Comment: You can use the `ylim` argument. eg. `ylim=c(0,2000)`

Comment: It's a good start. This tells you to focus on 0-400

Answer (score 2):

The bars to stay in the chart area. R calculates the axis dimensions based on your data and with default parameters even extends it a bit.

The axis with its labels is drawn for the boxplot only inside the label range.

If you draw a box around the figure, you will see that the plot uses up the space always the same disregarding of your data. So it is not the bars going outside the chart but the axis being restricted to the labels.

```
set.seed(12345)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot_random_hist <- function() {
  hist(rbeta(100,1,8)*runif(1))
  # plot a box to illustrate the plot area
  box(col="red")
}
replicate(4, plot_random_hist() )
```

Have a look at `par("usr")` to query the dimensions of your plot in user coordinates.

If you need to control the length of the axis and the ticks/labels you can use the `axis` command and suppress automatic axis in your `hist` call.

```
set.seed(12345)
hist(rbeta(100,1,8),yaxt="n")
at <- c(0,10,30,par("usr")[4])
axis(2,at=at,labels=round(at))
```